# End without with statement

Tags: excel, vba

i am getting error End without with statement on my code. Basically I want to check to see if a file exist, if it does not then msgbox if it does then open it, copy a range, and paste the range to a destination range. I also want to be able to do it for multiple files.

```
Sub test()

Dim WbookCheck As Workbook
Dim filepaths As String

On Error Resume Next
Set WbookCheck = Workbooks("LL-AD-ARROW.xls")
On Error GoTo 0

If WbookCheck Is Nothing Then 'not open....

    filepaths = "c:\Disti-Master\Data\LL-AD-ARROW.xls"

    If Dir(filepaths) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File is missing"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'file exists - open it
        Set WbookCheck = Workbooks.Open(filepaths)
        Cells.Select
           Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Activate
           Selection.Copy
           Windows("WW Disti Weekly Q116_Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Update").Range("D3").Activate
          Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing an **END IF**

Comment: ... and you have a dangling **End With** (before End Sub) as the error message says. If you formatted/indented your code you could easily find out yourself.

Comment: Why is this question down voted? I understand that such errors might not be up to the high standards of some other questions here. Yet, the question is valid, correctly tagged, contains well formatted code, is reproducible, and possibly an unsolvable pain in the neck for our new fellow programmer.

Comment: I wish VBA did it automatically, but I make it a habit to *always* put my `End With` or `End If`, right after I start the `With` or `If` statement, before typing anything else.  It also helps if you're adding a few `If` statements, to keep them clear.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, you guys are awesome! I am learning VBA now and I was able to rewrite the code differently to match my reporting needs. Can someone please teach me how to manipulate a source file based on a mapping and then vlookup transfer it in my master file?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub test()

Dim WbookCheck As Workbook
Dim filepaths As String

On Error Resume Next
Set WbookCheck = Workbooks("LL-AD-ARROW.xls")
On Error GoTo 0

    If WbookCheck Is Nothing Then 'not open....

        filepaths = "c:\Disti-Master\Data\LL-AD-ARROW.xls"

        If Dir(filepaths) = "" Then
            MsgBox "File is missing"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'file exists - open it
            Set WbookCheck = Workbooks.Open(filepaths)
            Cells.Select
               Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Activate
               Selection.Copy
               Windows("WW Disti Weekly Q116_Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Update").Range("D3").Activate
              Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much but I was able to rewrite the code differently to match my reporting. Can someone please teach me how to manupilate a source file based on a mapping and then vlookup trasnfer it in my master file?